# meromorphic functions on proper varieties are rational

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose $X$ is a proper variety over $\mathbb{C}$, is every meromorphic function rational? In the case of projective variety, can this be derived from Chow lemma? How does the GAGA principal illustrate on these ?

Comment: You have *Chow's theorem* in mind, not *Chow's lemma* , which  is about obtaining  complete varieties from projective ones

Comment: Thanks for your clarification! (The chow lemma says the existence of a proper birational morphism from a projective variety to any complete variety, while the chow theorem says an analytic subvariety is an algebraic variety.)And thanks for your references below.

Comment: You are welcome, dear mqx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every meromorphic function on a complete complex variety $X$ over $\mathbb C$ is indeed rational.
The proof is in Shafarevich's *Basic Algebraic Geometry 2*, Second Edition, Chap.VIII, §3, Theorem 1, pages 179-180.
The generalization of GAGA from projective varieties to complete ones is due to Grothendieck and can be found in SGA 1, exposé XII.
There is however no explicit mention of meromorphic functions in that exposé.